# Doctrine 2.0 NativeQuery ResultSetMapping for count(id)

Tags: sql, mapping, doctrine-orm

I generate an SQL from NativeQuery and this is the result sql:

> SELECT COUNT(id) AS tot,created_at FROM property WHERE created_at
>   BETWEEN '20120501000000' AND '20120521235959' GROUP BY
>   YEAR(created_at),MONTH(created_at),DAY(created_at);

This is my ResultSetMapping:

```
$rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('Entity\Property', 'p');
$rsm->addFieldResult('p','count(id)','tot'); // <-- this don't work
$rsm->addFieldResult('p','created_at','created_at');
```

The result running the above query direct on mysql is ok:

```
tot created_at
11  2012-05-02 11:23:25
11  2012-05-08 14:56:40
152 2012-05-16 14:43:46
5   2012-05-17 16:26:31
29  2012-05-18 14:55:33
```

But the result array the tot alias don't exist!!

The Question is:

How i set ResultSetMapping correctly for **count(id)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
$rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'tot', 'tot');
```

as your **column as been renamed** with `COUNT(id) AS tot`. If remove the `tot` alias you can use your original code:

```
$rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'COUNT(id)', 'tot');
```