# Subqueries in symfony

Tags: mysql, symfony

I have a Review Entity which contains the fields:

```
id
userID
bookID
review
```

and then a Rating Entity which contains the fields:

```
id
reviewID
userID
rating
```

The rating could possible store 0 or a 1.

How would I perform a query using symfony to count all ratings from the Rating table that are equal to 1 and then count the ratings that are equal to 0 then minus the count for 0 ratings from the count for 1 ratings and return it for each review?

How would I do that? Seems a very tricky one

Comment: Are your entities related one way or another?! (OneToMany/MenyToOne relationship)

Comment: @Preciel Yeah one to many and many to one

Comment: Then can you post your entity files plz?! I don't see how they're linked with so little data... Else, there is nothing hard to your question, it all happen in twig, you will do something like `{% for rating in review.rating %}` and then loop through the ratings... I will post a full reply when your question will be updated (or someone else maybe if faster than me)

Comment: Hi there KTOV. I'm not sure I understand the Doctrine query you need? So you want: `COUNT(ra.rating = 1) - COUNT(ra.rating = 0)` and then with this number (the result) what do you want to do with it? The query I show is not SQL. Somehow you want to see the reviews, but since there is a relationship between Review and Rating entities, why not get all the Ratings with ra.rating = 1, and then get the reviews. Is that what you need?

Comment: Agree with AlvinBunk

Answer (score 0):

Alright as you are using Symfony I assume you are also use Doctrine.

Doctrine allows you to perform **Native Queries**. Have a look on how to execute a native query [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).
On MySQL you may perform **Subqueries**, have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html) on how to do it.

Then try something like this:

`SELECT rv.* , ((SELECT count(*) FROM ratings ra WHERE ra.rating = 1 AND id rv.id = ra.reviewID) - (SELECT count(*) FROM ratings ra WHERE ra.rating = 0 AND id rv.id = ra.reviewID)) as result FROM review rv;`

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691139/doctrine-2-0-nativequery-resultsetmapping-for-countid) on how to get the value attached to the entity.

Comment: If you did read the comments, you would have understood that there is no need of what you just posed... Symfony will do the subqueries as long as entities are related to each others... And for god sake, use DQL... [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293878/make-an-iterable-array-of-objects-in-php-for-twig) you can find a good example of DQL I wrote not long ago

Comment: @Preciel gragonmau's answer is a correct one. KTOV needs to use Doctrine for what he wants to do! Although I think KTOV needs to clarify the exact query he actually needs.

Comment: @KTOV there is any way to apply count function using DQL?
Usually when performing this kind of calculated fields I prefer doing it on the database size rather than on PHP side. The database tend to be much more prepared to deal with this kind of operation rather then the web server, sometimes it may lead to a performance issue. That's why I suggested to use Native Query instead of DQL.